# Distribution of modulus of sum of complex numbers with known moduli

Tags: probability-distributions, complex-numbers, summation

If a finite set of complex numbers have known moduli but uniformly distributed arguments, what is the distribution of the modulus of their sum?

(The problem arises from the practical problem of summing audio sources of unknown phase.  I can see it tends to the Rayleigh and Rice distributions under certain conditions.  I'm hoping for a general form with parameters one can estimate from a list of magnitudes.)